# Locally free modules are flat

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness

The following theorem is well-known in commutative algebra:

> Let $A$ be a ring. Suppose that, for all prime ideals $\frak p$ of $A$, the module $M_\frak p$ is flat over $A_\frak p$. Then $M$ is flat over $A$.

Up until now, I never used this theorem but always:

- free modules are flat
- if a module is torsion over a domain, then it is not flat
- extension of scalars preserves flatness

etc. I would like to see some concrete, non-trivial examples of the above theorem in use, where using this theorem is favorable over using any three of the above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what the hint means, the formula you give doesn't define a module structure ($(a+b)\cdot (x,y) = (ax+bx,y) \neq (ax,y)+(bx,y) = (ax+bx,2y)$ )

Comment: @MaximeRamzi he said 'acts trivially on the second component' Maybe he meant $a\cdot (x,y)=(ax,0)$ ? The module structure is defined by the morphism of rings $k\to k\otimes k,1\mapsto (1,0)$ ?

Comment: What is $k$ here? Is it any commutative unital ring?

Comment: @Mark $k$ is a field

Comment: That is still not a module structure (unital at least - which we always assume in this kind of business). Are you sure your teacher said "$k$-module", or did they maybe say "$k[X]$-module" ? Because trivially on the second component doesn't mean anything just for $k$

Comment: Well, a module over a field is always free (as this is a vector space), and so it is flat. So you don't need localizations for this example.

Comment: @Mark MaximeRamzi thank you for your comments, I suppose I just have to forget my teacher's example :P My question remains : is there an example to illustrate how this theorem can be used ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=\mathbb Z$ and $M=\{a/b\in\mathbb Q\mid b\text{ is squarefree}\}$. Let $p$ be a prime. We claim that $M_{(p)}\cong\Bbb Z_{(p)}$. To this end, let $m\in M_{(p)}$. Then we can write $$m=\frac{a}{bp^{n}},$$ where $b\notin(p)$ and $n\in\{0,1\}$. Define a linear map $\phi:M_{(p)}\to\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ by $\phi(m)=pm$. Conversely, define $\psi:\Bbb Z_{(p)}\to M_{(p)}$ by $\psi(f)=f/p$. Notice that $$\frac{f}p=\frac{(a/p)}{b}$$ for some $b\notin (p)$ and $a/p\in M$. Verify that $\psi$ and $\phi$ are inverses of each other.

Thus $M_{(p)}$ is free and hence flat as a $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$-module. It follows that $M$ is a flat $\mathbb Z$ module.